# How to select Amazon Machine Image (linux distribution) to AWS EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just started with Amazon Web Services and want to start an EC2 instance. I need to select an Amazon Machine Image (linux distribution). I have almost no previous knowledge of Linux and don't know how to make my choice. Amazon recommend their own "Amazon Linux AMI", of course. Many tutorials on youtube prefer Ubuntu.

What are the pros and cons? Any reason not to choose Amazon Linux? How can I make my choice? Does it really matter what I actually choose?

I will run PHP and maybe later mySQL. I have an Amazon S3 bucket and planning to use my EC2 instance to get/put files to S3.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can start with Amazon Linux (a similar centos/Redhat linux), because it has several pre-install packages

> The Amazon Linux AMI is an EBS-backed, AWS-supported image. The default image includes AWS command line tools, Python, Ruby, Perl, and Java. The repositories include Docker, PHP, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and other packages.

When you start using with Amazon linux, you will know if it is suitable for your application or not. For current usage (PHP + MySQL), it is no any problem to support your application.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand  which pre-installed packages. I have no plans to use Python, Ruby, Perl, and Java. What does "The repositories include" means? I still have to install PHP and MySQL to use it? Same with e.g Ubuntu.

Comment: As I said, in your case, you can use whatever you like. Ubuntu is also a good choice.

Comment: sudo apt-get install <repo-name>